# How to copy a file fron windows os to cloudera ? I also want to import the .csv file in to the hive, how can i do that?

Tags: hadoop, hive, bigdata, cloudera, hiveql

How to copy a file from windows OS to cloudera ? I also want to import the .csv file in to the hive, how can i do that ? Please help me to get it done.

Answer (score 0):

To get the file into Linux you will need to either ftp it to the CentOS CLoudera box or mount a file share and copy it from there.

Once on the CentOS/Cloudera box you can open the web browser and log into Cloudera Manager and Hue which is the user interface to Hive/Pig etc. There are icons across the top with the third from the left being Beeswax/Hive. Click on that icon and start from there.

Your other choice once you have the file on the Cloudera box is to use the Hadoop fs commands found [HERE](http://archive.cloudera.com/cdh4/cdh/4/hadoop/hadoop-project-dist/hadoop-common/FileSystemShell.html) specifically copyFromLocal

To load your file into Hive you can do one of two things. Load it into a single large staging field and then parse it into fields you want using offsets like so:

```
LOAD DATA INPATH '/user/xyz/Inbound/files/target.csv' INTO TABLE 'myTable'
```

This loads the entire record into a single field. Then you would do the following once loaded.

```
INSERT OVERWRITE TABLE myTable SELECT
regexp_extract(col_value, '^(?:([^,]*)\,?)(1)', 1) New_Field_name1
regexp_extract(col_value, '^(?:([^,]*)\,?)(5)', 1) New_Field_name2
......
FROM myTable;
```

The syntax looks challenging but it is not bad, you will just have to read up on [HiveQL](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/LanguageManual) 
Hue also allows you to load a CSV into the individual fields but you have to add the field names yourself. I have never done that before though.